# Electron focus() not working in webview

Tags: javascript, html, webview, electron

Im trying to set the focus on an element in the webview after it loses his focus

```
<webview src="http://www.example.com/" id="target-view"  preload="js/hooker.js" autosize minwidth="100%" minheight="100%"></webview>
```

i inject the js file to webview and catch the focus/blur events

```
function blur(event) {
  if(!(event.target instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement)) {
    currentElement = null;
    ipcRenderer.sendToHost('onScreenKeyboard', 'hide');
  }
}

function focus(event) {
  if (event.target instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) {
    currentElement = event.target;
    ipcRenderer.sendToHost('onScreenKeyboard', 'show');
  }
}

ipcRenderer.on('key' , function(event , data){
  switch(data) {
    case 'RETURN':
      currentElement = null;
      break;
    default:
      currentElement.value+=data;
      currentElement.focus(); // this is not working
      break;
  }
});
```

in my index.html i show up a keyboard and when i click on the button the element in the webview calls blur

and i want to set the focus back to the input html but its not working